# Order approve mail

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-vendor

I am using **Marketplace** Extension in my Website. Once customer Bought Seller product in My website after that admin approve that product that time that seller got conformation mail for that everything is working fine.

But my problem is I want to add some custom value on that I can't able to find that file location can any one tell me where is the location of that mail

```
public function massStatusAction()
    {
        $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
        $countOrder = 0;

        foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
            if($order->getStatus()=='pending'){
                $order->setStatus('processing')->save();
                $countOrder++;

                // for mail to seller start
                $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
                $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$orderId);
                $_collection->addFieldToSelect('mageproownerid')
                            ->distinct(true);
                foreach($_collection as $collection){
                    $fetchsale = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
                    $fetchsale->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$orderId);   
                    $fetchsale->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',$collection->getMageproownerid());
                    $totalprice ='';
                    $orderinfo = '';
                        $style='style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc";';
                        $tax="<tr><td ".$style."><h3>Tax</h3></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr><tr>";
                        $options="<tr><td ".$style."><h3>Product Options</h3></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr><tr><td ".$style."><b>Options</b></td><td ".$style."><b>Value</b></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr>";        
                    foreach($fetchsale as $res){
                        $orderinfo = $orderinfo."<tr>
                                        <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style." >".$res['mageproname']."</td>
                                        <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style.">".Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($res['mageproid'])->getSku()."</td>
                                        <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style." >".$res['magequantity']."</td>
                                        <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style.">".Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($res['mageproprice'])."</td>
                                     </tr>";    

                        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
                            if($item->getProductId()==$res['mageproid']){
                                $taxAmount=Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($item->getTaxAmount());
                                $tax=$tax."<tr><td ".$style."><b>Tax Amount</b></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style.">".$taxAmount."</td></tr>";
                                $temp=$item->getProductOptions();
                                foreach($temp['options'] as $data){
                                    $optionflag=1;
                                    $options=$options."<tr><td ".$style."><b>".$data['label']."</b></td><td ".$style.">".$data['value']."</td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr>";
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                        $totalprice = $totalprice+$res['mageproprice'];
                        $userdata = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($res['mageproownerid']);              
                        $Username = $userdata['firstname'];
                        $useremail = $userdata['email'];            
                    }

                    $shipcharge = $order->getShippingAmount();
                    if($item->getTaxAmount()>0){
                        $orderinfo=$orderinfo.$tax;
                    }
                    if($optionflag==1){
                        $orderinfo=$orderinfo.$options;
                    }
                    $orderinfo = $orderinfo."</tbody><tbody><tr>
                                                <td align='right' style='padding:3px 9px' colspan='3'>Grandtotal</td>
                                                <td align='right' style='padding:3px 9px' colspan='3'><span>".Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($totalprice+$item->getTaxAmount())."</span></td>
                                            </tr>";

                    $billingId = $order->getBillingAddress()->getId();
                    $billaddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($billingId);
                    $billinginfo = $billaddress['firstname'].'<br/>'.$billaddress['street'].'<br/>'.$billaddress['city'].' '.$billaddress['region'].' '.$billaddress['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($billaddress['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$billaddress['telephone'];  

                    if($order->getShippingAddress()!='')
                        $shippingId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
                    else
                        $shippingId = $billingId;
                    $address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingId);                
                    $shippinginfo = $address['firstname'].'<br/>'.$address['street'].'<br/>'.$address['city'].' '.$address['region'].' '.$address['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($address['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$address['telephone']; 

                    $payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
                    if($order->getShippingAddress()){
                        $shippingId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
                        $address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingId);                
                        $shippinginfo = $address['firstname'].'<br/>'.$address['street'].'<br/>'.$address['city'].' '.$address['region'].' '.$address['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($address['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$address['telephone']; 
                        $shipping = $order->getShippingDescription();   
                        $shippinfo = $shippinginfo;
                        $shippingd = $shipping;     
                    }
                    $emailTemp = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('webkulorderinvoice');

                    $emailTempVariables = array();              
                    $adminEmail=Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                    $adminUsername = 'Admin';
                    if(isset($res['seller_order_id']) && $res['seller_order_id']!==NULL && $res['seller_order_id']!=="")
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $res['seller_order_id'];
                    else
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $res['magerealorderid'];
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = $res['cleared_at'];
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar4'] = $billinginfo;
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar5'] = $payment;
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar6'] = $shippinfo;
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar9'] = $shippingd;
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar8'] = $orderinfo;
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar3'] =$Username;

                    $processedTemplate = $emailTemp->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);

                    $emailTemp->setSenderName($adminUsername);
                    $emailTemp->setSenderEmail($adminEmail);
                    $emailTemp->send($useremail,$Username,$emailTempVariables);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Assign seller Sku**

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php /* Custom Code */?>
        <?php $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
        //$_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$order->getEntityId());
        $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',$_item->getProductId());  
          foreach($_collection as $res){
            $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
             $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id=?', $res->getMpassignproductId());
            $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord); 
            if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
                foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
                    { 
                        $sku=$assignproduct['sku'];
                    }
                     }else {
                        $sku=$_item->getSku();
                    }
                }
        ?>
<?php /* Custom Code */?>
```

How to call this code Assign seller sku in that `massStatusAction()`

Comment: paste the  config.xml of module

Comment: Check my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function massStatusAction()
    {
        $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
        $countOrder = 0;

        foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
            if($order->getStatus()=='pending'){
                $order->setStatus('processing')->save();
                $countOrder++;

                // for mail to seller start
                $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
                $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$orderId);
                $_collection->addFieldToSelect('mageproownerid')
                            ->distinct(true);
                foreach($_collection as $collection){
                    $fetchsale = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
                    $fetchsale->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$orderId);   
                    $fetchsale->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',$collection->getMageproownerid());
                    $totalprice ='';
                    $orderinfo = '';
                        $style='style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc";';
                        $tax="<tr><td ".$style."><h3>Tax</h3></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr><tr>";
                        $options="<tr><td ".$style."><h3>Product Options</h3></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr><tr><td ".$style."><b>Options</b></td><td ".$style."><b>Value</b></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr>";        
                    foreach($fetchsale as $res){
                 $_collection1 = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
            //$_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$orderId);
            $_collection1->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',$res['mageproid']);  
              foreach($_collection1 as $res1){
                $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
                 $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id=?', $res1->getMpassignproductId());
                $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord); 
                if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
                    foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
                        { 
                            $sku=$assignproduct['sku'];
                        }
                         }else {
                            $sku=$_item->getSku();
                        }
                    }
                        $orderinfo = $orderinfo."<tr>
                                        <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style." >".$res['mageproname']."</td>
                                        <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style.">".$sku."</td>
                                        <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style." >".$res['magequantity']."</td>
                                        <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style.">".Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($res['mageproprice'])."</td>
                                     </tr>";    

                        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){

                            if($item->getProductId()==$res['mageproid']){
                                $taxAmount=Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($item->getTaxAmount());
                                $tax=$tax."<tr><td ".$style."><b>Tax Amount</b></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style.">".$taxAmount."</td></tr>";
                                $temp=$item->getProductOptions();
                                foreach($temp['options'] as $data){
                                    $optionflag=1;
                                    $options=$options."<tr><td ".$style."><b>".$data['label']."</b></td><td ".$style.">".$data['value']."</td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr>";
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                        $totalprice = $totalprice+$res['mageproprice'];
                        $userdata = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($res['mageproownerid']);              
                        $Username = $userdata['firstname'];
                        $useremail = $userdata['email'];            
                    }

                    $shipcharge = $order->getShippingAmount();
                    if($item->getTaxAmount()>0){
                        $orderinfo=$orderinfo.$tax;
                    }
                    if($optionflag==1){
                        $orderinfo=$orderinfo.$options;
                    }
                    $orderinfo = $orderinfo."</tbody><tbody><tr>
                                                <td align='right' style='padding:3px 9px' colspan='3'>Grandtotal</td>
                                                <td align='right' style='padding:3px 9px' colspan='3'><span>".Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($totalprice+$item->getTaxAmount())."</span></td>
                                            </tr>";

                    $billingId = $order->getBillingAddress()->getId();
                    $billaddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($billingId);
                    $billinginfo = $billaddress['firstname'].'<br/>'.$billaddress['street'].'<br/>'.$billaddress['city'].' '.$billaddress['region'].' '.$billaddress['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($billaddress['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$billaddress['telephone'];  

                    if($order->getShippingAddress()!='')
                        $shippingId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
                    else
                        $shippingId = $billingId;
                    $address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingId);                
                    $shippinginfo = $address['firstname'].'<br/>'.$address['street'].'<br/>'.$address['city'].' '.$address['region'].' '.$address['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($address['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$address['telephone']; 

                    $payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
                    if($order->getShippingAddress()){
                        $shippingId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
                        $address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingId);                
                        $shippinginfo = $address['firstname'].'<br/>'.$address['street'].'<br/>'.$address['city'].' '.$address['region'].' '.$address['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($address['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$address['telephone']; 
                        $shipping = $order->getShippingDescription();   
                        $shippinfo = $shippinginfo;
                        $shippingd = $shipping;     
                    }
                    $emailTemp = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('webkulorderinvoice');

                    $emailTempVariables = array();              
                    $adminEmail=Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                    $adminUsername = 'Admin';
                    if(isset($res['seller_order_id']) && $res['seller_order_id']!==NULL && $res['seller_order_id']!=="")
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $res['seller_order_id'];
                    else
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $res['magerealorderid'];
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = $res['cleared_at'];
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar4'] = $billinginfo;
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar5'] = $payment;
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar6'] = $shippinfo;
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar9'] = $shippingd;
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar8'] = $orderinfo;
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar3'] =$Username;

                    $processedTemplate = $emailTemp->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);

                    $emailTemp->setSenderName($adminUsername);
                    $emailTemp->setSenderEmail($adminEmail);
                    $emailTemp->send($useremail,$Username,$emailTempVariables);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: i already check is html file how i add php code

Comment: add your variable and pass those variable when it processed.

Comment: Actually my problem is it already shows sku but i want to get assign seller sku so i can't able to find that file of variable

Comment: go to action what is admin approve action check that there must some model calling check in that

Comment: you know the class name

Comment: paste the code where admin approve the order

Comment: i update my observer.php

Comment: no code for that check the admin controller

Comment: i can't find anything here also. i updated my code

Comment: for this code it is approving the order ??

Comment: Yes after approve order only customer got a mail

Comment: even i search full module i can't able to find that code

Comment: is there any button or mass action for approval the order?

Comment: Yes Approve order submit is there

Comment: action of that button kindly post that action code

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: How to call this assign seller sku in that method

Comment: updated the answer and kindly award the bounty on bounty question..

Comment: where i need to add it shows empty can you please update full method

Comment: after `foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){  ` this line.

Comment: But above only it getting sku it will work

Comment: now i added the code try that

Comment: Call to a member function getSku() on a non-object

Comment: It's working i used this in else $sku=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($res['mageproid'])->getSku();

Comment: share url of award the bounty on bounty question

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101029/wrong-customer-account-creation-date