# Wrong Customer Account Creation date

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9. In backend Manage Customer under Account  **Customer Account Creation on**  it shows wrong date.

I can't able to point out the problem can any one suggest this problem

[image]

in **config.xml**

```
<general>
            <locale>
                <code>en_US</code>
                <timezone>Asia/Calcutta</timezone>
            </locale>
        </general>
```

in **mage.php**

```
//date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
                date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
```

Comment: admin side check in configuration  in locale `Timezone`

Comment: That's fine because login time is working fine Account creation time only wrong

Comment: can you paste screenshot of time zone?

Comment: did you set it  install time or later?

Comment: Where? which means

Comment: if you set it later then it will not effect to make sure you have right time try this in your phtml file `echo date('y/m/d h:i:s');` and check the output

Comment: can you please tell me the file path

Comment: product view a this code and check the output... template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Comment: Yes it shows wrong date and time 16/02/12 11:41:42

Comment: How to fix this

Comment: i added the answer kindly check and feedback..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set your timezone manually

first go to

`app/etc/config.xml`  add your time zone here

```
<general>
            <locale>
                <code>en_US</code>
                <timezone>Asia/Dubai</timezone>
            </locale>
        </general>
```

second go to `app/Mage.php`

on line `768`

change this line too

`date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

to your `timezone`

`date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai');`

Comment: where i can add can you please give me the location

Comment: both file location are there kindly change to your timezone.

Comment: Ok i will check and give you feed back soon

Comment: still now same problem also echo date('y/m/d h:i:s'); show wrong date only

Comment: did you do the both work add your timzone in config.xml and Mage.php

Comment: Yes i added both place

Comment: what you added can you post that? because i did that myself i have the same problem this solution work for me.

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: did you removed th cache folder? from var/cache?

Comment: yes i already did that also

Comment: it's available only i selected from dropdown only

Comment: it give me correct time `12:07` just change in Mage.php

Comment: Share your code here

Comment: `$localConfig = simplexml_load_file($localConfigFile); 
                date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');` this i added on line `768`

Comment: I added same code but it shows 16/02/15 12:34:43 is anything else i need to change

Comment: this is correct now create account and check created date..

Comment: What you set in back end

Comment: it won't work previous users

Comment: the customer already created you cannot change the created at value for new customer check it..

Comment: Is it possible to change previous date

Comment: While echo it shows wrong date only 16/02/15 01:32:53

Comment: it is not showing wrong time try with `echo date('y/m/d h:i:s A'); ` it will show am and pm too

Comment: Time is fine but year and date it showing wrong 16/02/15 03:00:07 PM

Comment: `16` is year `02` is month `15` is day ad you can see `y/m/d` you change `d/m/Y` and see the changes

Comment: Oh sorry bro is it possible to change old customer date's

Comment: change from database or  create script and change the values.

Comment: Ok i will check it

Comment: it's already awarded bro

Comment: read this how to award http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: Sorry check now

Answer (score 1):

Check your server's date & time is correct.

Check that your Magento locale settings (esp. timezone) is set properly.

Comment: How to check server time

Comment: If you have command line access, `date` would most likely the command to show current date and time (-zone).

If you don't, connect via FTP, upload any file and see if the creation date and time is something near your current local time. (There might be some seconds difference due to delay caused by the actual file transfer and refreshing the directory view).

Comment: No i don't have that acess

Comment: If you don't, connect via FTP, upload any file and see if the creation date and time is something near your current local time. (There might be some seconds difference due to delay caused by the actual file transfer and refreshing the directory view).
Sorry, that part of the comment didn't go through the first time since i hit "RETURN" too fast :-)

Comment: I checked server time also not a problem on that it shows current time only

Comment: Ok, last thing I can imagine of is that MySQL time is somehow wrong.

Comment: Are customer creation times *always* wrong or just *sometimes*?

I had the issue that customer creation and last-login dates weren't logged at all. Time always showed something like 1970-01-01. There's an option to enable that logging, I think it was `Configuration -> Advanced/System -> Log -> Enable Log`.

Comment: Some time only problem if i create today it shows correct date some previously created account time show some random month

Answer (score 0):

This might be similar to [Customer created_at Date off by months](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18062/customer-created-at-date-off-by-months). I had same issue in one of my Magento.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue few days back all I did was creating my custom module Namespace > Modulename > Model > Entity Attribute > Backend > Time > Created.php

copy the Created.php file from app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Time

after copying this file find and comment out the lines

```
$zendDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->utcDate(null, $date, true, $this->_getFormat($date));
        $object->setData($attributeCode, $zendDate->getIso());
```

In both beforeSave and afterSave function. The utcDate conversion is causing this weird issue. I did the above mentioned thing and this got resolved the very next moment.